# orphaned case error in a switch statments

Tags: java

i wrote a small program in java
the user enter a number to get his multiplication table
and then type the maximum length of that table

but in the third case (case r) i got an error orphaned case
and it seems clean code to me

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Multiplication Table v1.0");
    System.out.println("Developped By Roy Jalbout");
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    System.out.println("Type 'E' To Quit The Program\nType 'H' To Read The Help File\nType 'R' To Run The Program");
    char act = (char)System.in.read();
    switch (act) {
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
           System.exit(0);
           break;
       case 'h':
       case 'H':
           System.out.println("The Multiplication Table Version 1.0 Developped By Roy Jalbout is A Simple Program All you have to do is to choose the number that you want to get his multiplication table and then choose the maximum lenght of that table");
           System.out.println("----------------------------------");
           System.out.println("Type back to go to the main thread");
           String mainthread = scn.next();
           if ("back".equals(mainthread)){
               JavaApplication2.main(args);
               break;
       case 'r':
       case 'R':
             Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
               System.out.print("Enter A Number To Get His Multiplication Table : ");
           int num = scn.nextInt();
           System.out.print("Enter The Max Number Of The Multiplication Table : ");
           int max = scn.nextInt();
           int b=1;
          while (b<=max){
               System.out.println(num + " * " + b + " = " + b*num);
               b++;
               JavaApplication2.main(args);
           }   
    default:
               System.out.println(act + " is an Invalid Choice");
           }
    }
    }
}
```

any help???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
       if ("back".equals(mainthread)){
           JavaApplication2.main(args);// you are not closing the brace here..
           break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the orphaned case, for me, was there was a couple of not closed curly brackets after I began the switch case. 
For example, there was a loop inside a case which I had not closed.
Once I closed there was no obstacles